# Maven dependency stripVersion creates wrong classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am trying to compile a project with Maven (through Eclipse), while stripping versions from dependency JARs. I have the following in my pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.8</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
            <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

And indeed, the JARs are copied into lib/ without the version numbers. Alas, I get ClassNotFound, because the MANIFEST.MF in the generated executable JAR contains a classpath referring to the files *including* the version numbers, which naturally are not there.

What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix it?

Edit: JAR is created with maven-jar-plugin:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.6</version>
<configuration>
    <archive>
        <manifest>
            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
            <mainClass>my.main.class</mainClass>
            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
          <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
        </manifest>
    </archive>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

I am using `Run as -> Maven Install` (Eclipse with m2e plugin)

Comment: How are you generating the execuable JAR? Usually, using the dependency plugin is not needed for that.

Comment: Using maven-jar-plugin. I added the configuration from my pom.xml.
Do you mean that maven-jar-plugin can copy dependencies on it's own? How can I tell it to strip version numbers?

Comment: You can use the [shade-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) or the [assembly-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/components/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) for that purpose. Both plugins are able to create a _FAT JAR_ (in which you do not need to configure any library names). The assembly plugin is also able to create a ZIP file - for example - that has the structure that you maybe want: An executable JAR and its libraries in a lib directory. In that case you must configure the [jar-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/) to refer to the correct libs.

Comment: For configuring the jar-plugin, see also the [Maver Archiver Reference](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/index.html).

Comment: Thank you. I am not interested in creating a FAT JAR. As far as I could see, using assembly-plugin would mean I have to create my own assembly-descriptor for this task (please correct me if I'm wrong!), which I would rather avoid. 
As for jar-plugin - I can't find the option to refer to the libs. Can you point me to the correct option to set? (Is it `includes`? This seems to me like an option to include resources, isn't it?)

Comment: Regarding the assembly plugin: Yes, you have to provide an assembly ( which will be a rather short one). But you are configuring the same anyway - with the dependency plugin. So what? The jar plugin knows a configuration for the classpath: Simply add `<classpathLayoutType>custom</classpathLayoutType>` and `<customClasspathLayout>$${artifact.groupId}.$${artifact.artifactId}.$${artifact.extension}</customClasspathLayout>` to the archiver configuration. We do so in combination with the assembly plugin.

Comment: The assembly plugin has the nice feature that it adds the produced assembly to the artifacts that must be uploaded. So in the end it is upload to our repo manager.

Answer (score 4):

Change the maven-jar-plugin to create a custom classpath layout without the version

Example:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <classpathLayoutType>custom</classpathLayoutType>
                        <customClasspathLayout>lib/$${artifact.artifactId}.$${artifact.extension}</customClasspathLayout>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```